# How to do I delete/edit a package and its release file list in test.pypi.org?

Tags: pypi

I do not see a way to delete entire packages or specific releases of a package from test.pypi.org. I do see that that I can do this on testpypi.python.org, but editing there does not seem to remove the data from test.pypi.org. Is this by design? If not, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can delete packages from test PyPI:

1. go to your package, i.e. https://test.pypi.org/manage/project/bank2ynab/releases/
2. you'll see a listing like this one: [image]
3. point to "options" and click on "delete".

Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer shows how to delete specific releases. If instead you want to delete the entire package from TestPyPI, go to "settings"...

[image]

and scroll down until you see this dialogue:

[image]